# Is the product of two Lie groupoids always a Lie groupoid?

Tags: category-theory, manifolds, lie-groupoids

Let $\mathcal{G}=[G_1 \rightrightarrows G_0]$ and $\mathcal{H}=[H_1 \rightrightarrows H_0]$ be two Lie groupoids. Consider the product category $\mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{H}$.

**My question:**

Is the product category $\mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{H}$  always a Lie groupoid with respect to the standard structure maps induced from the structure maps of Lie groupoids $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$?

*Particularly, I am not able to convince myself that source map  $s_{\mathcal{G}} \times s_{\mathcal{H}}: G_1 \times H_1 \rightarrow G_0 \times H_0$ and target map $t_{\mathcal{G}} \times t_{\mathcal{H}}: G_1 \times H_1 \rightarrow G_0 \times H_0$ are always submersions.* (Here $s_{\mathcal{G}}$, $t_{\mathcal{G}}$ are source and target maps of the Lie groupoid $\mathcal{G}$ and $s_{\mathcal{H}}$, $t_{\mathcal{H}}$ are source and target maps of the Lie groupoid $\mathcal{H}$ )

If the answer to my question is negative, then under what conditions on $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ the product category $\mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{H}$ is a Lie groupoid with the induced structure maps?

Comment: Don't you just need to know that products of submersions are submersions?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, but I don't know whether its true or not!

Comment: It's true. After taking derivatives you just need to check that the product of surjective linear maps is surjective, which is straightforward.